# Can't get Flow to run with each babel recompile

Tags: flowtype, create-react-app

I have Flow setup per the instructions. My `package.json`:

```
{
  […],
  "devDependencies": {
    "flow-bin": "^0.82.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  […]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "babel",
    "prepublish": "npm run build",
    "flow": "flow",

  }
}
```

When I run `npm run-script flow` I get what I expect from flow, plus an error:

> Error
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/reducers/brands.js:65:67
>
> ```
> Cannot resolve name `action`.
>
>    65| export function brandReducer(state: BrandState = brandState, Action: action) {
>
> Found 1 error
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 2
> npm ERR! wsbc.vpn@0.1.0 flow: `flow`
> npm ERR! Exit status 2
> ```

Why am I seeing this errno 2? Because flow found a type error and returned that status?

Also, `flow` does not run with each recompile when running my application as `npm start` as usual. Is it possible to make this happen once the flow server is started in the background?

Is there something wrong with my setup?

Comment: Flow is running in the background, but it won't tell you about failures unless you've set up something to ask it for the current errors.

Comment: Yes I tried adding `flow status` to the flow entry under `scripts` above but it doesn't "fire" with each re-compile. Works fine from the CLI...